# Get the list of all hostnames a website fetches resources from

Tags: vpn, google-chrome-devtools

My VPN service allows me to black/ or whitelist certain hostnames. If for example I want to connect to Youtube not through VPN I need to add to my list not only the youtube's main domain but also a bunch of resource domains like ytimg.com and probably some others. Is it possible to get the list of all hostnames my browser has been connected to using dev tools or by some other means?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open developer tools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
2. click on network

[image: netork]

3. right-click on the attributes and enable `URL`

[image]

4. load a site of your choice